# jQuery "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, each

I have the following json array returning from an ajax call:

`{"err":"err_type","fields":["field1","field2"]}`

when tryin to print it out with this function:

```
$.each(data.fields, function (i, field) {
    console.log(field);
    $.each(field, function (j, f) {
        $('[name="'+f+'"]').addClass('form_err');
        console.log(f);
    });
});
```

i get this:

```
data1

TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
...turn function(b){return db(a,b).length>0}}),contains:fb(function(a){return funct...
```

and so i can't figure out how to use this array! Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are iterating a string, you don't need two .each() functions

```
$.each(data.fields, function (i, field) {
    $('[name="'+field+'"]').addClass('form_err');
    console.log(field);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to add `dataType: 'json';` so that it can be looped as an array and not a string.

Comment: bless your soul

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  another loopin `$.each()`:

```
$.each(data.fields, function (i, field) {
   console.log(field);
   $('[name="'+field+'"]').addClass('form_err');
});
```

---

`data.fields` is an array which contains `strings` only, so you don't need to loopin again. You just need to loopin only when if it would be another array object with `{key:value}` pairs.

Answer (score -2):

In your main loop, the "field" var is not an array, so you can't use "each" on it.