# Why does 'TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a' occur?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

When I send a variable and concatenate with another variable after converting the variables into string then this error shows me 'TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a'. I don't understand why my jquery code is as below:

```
$(document).on('change', '.AccountType', function () {


        var MemberId = document.getElementById("MemberId").value;           
        var AccountType = document.getElementById("AccountType").value;
        var acno = MemberId + AccountType;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'getAccountno',
            data: {'id': acno},
            success: function (data) {
               $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                    $('#AccountNo').empty();
                    document.getElementById("AccountNo").value = data;
                   });
            },
            error: function () {
                    alert("Something happening unexpected, Error!");
            }
        });

    });
```

and my controller is as below:

```
 public function getAccountno(Request $request){
    if($i<=9){ $i = '0'.$i};
    $AccountNo = $request->id;
    $AccountNo = (string)$AccountNo . (string)$i;
    $i++;
    $data = DB::table('accountopens')
        ->select('AccountNo')
        ->where('AccountNo', $AccountNo)
        ->get();
    if($data == null){
        return response()->json($AccountNo);
    }
    else{
        $i++;
        return response()->json((string)$AccountNo . (string)$i);
    }


}
```

Please describe the error...

Comment: What is the exactly line that this error happen? It is on JS or PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429957/jquery-typeerror-invalid-in-operand-a)

Comment: this occurs in php laravel controller. the exact line may in 'getAccountno () function line no 3 and 14. @David Rodrigues

Comment: the error is on js file and I used $.each() wheather response is not an array, that's why the error occurs.

Comment: Why do you need an `each` loop for a string in the first place?

Comment: that was my mistake, finally i detected that. @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

**$.each** expects an array, whereas you're passing it an object. If you change your data line to:

```
data: [{'id': acno}],
```

it should get rid of the error.